# Outlook for Mac Select/Remove Columns

Tags: ms-office

I am a frequent user of Outlook. Recently migrated from Windows to a MacBook.

In the new ad well as old Outlook App of Mac, I don’t see the options to add or remove columns as I used to get in the Windows version. Is there a way to get that options on the new Outlook version for Mac?